# Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, html

I am trying to call a function which is defined in functions.php. But I can’t figure out why this error is coming.

Let me tell you in detail what I am trying to accomplish: there are two header files — client and admin. The client header will be accessed when the user enters into a page through index.php, but admin header will be accessed after an admin successfuly logged in.

In the functions.php this is the function I have defined:

```
function get_my_header(){
  if(is_home()){ 
    get_header('client'); 
  }
  elseif(is_page('dashboard')){ 
    get_header('own'); 
  }
}
```

from index.php `get_my_header()` is called with no error but when I try to access the same function from the admin page I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `get_my_header()`

The page where this error is coming has only this one line:

```
<?php get_my_header(); ?>
```

Comment: do you have the function in the `class`?

Comment: `require_once(file.php);`

Answer (score 1):

The most common causes of this are:

- The file you think is being included, isn't being included.
- Your calling the function prior to including the file

Based on your description as a header a file - I think the first is most likely. As you also mention that it's in an admin page that it doesn't work on - does the admin page live in a sub directory e.g:

```
httpdocs/
   index.php
   admin/
       admin_index.php
```

If it does - the file path to the include file may be wrong, depending on your `error_reporting()` settings you may or may not be alerted to this.

One way to debug this would be to use `require()` instead of `include()` on the functions file - as that creates a fatal error if PHP can't find the script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: First I would like to tell you is that - all files resides in one folder. Second how will i include or require functions.php in my admin-index.php

Comment: Ah that would be why you cant use the function then. Follow the link in my post - there's also a comment below your question that shows include

Comment: sorry i can't find the link  pls specify which one ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I manage to get into "header-admin.php" using "include('header-admin.php') in dashboard.php. But now stuck in this header-admin.php file. Now a new error is coming :                              Fatal error :  Call to undefined function wp_enqueue_script().  Pls help??